# Spring Kafka 1.3.9.RELEASE and apache kafka client 1.1.1 compatibility

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I was using Spring Kafka 1.3.8 version with apache kafka client 0.11.0.2. Since my broker is getting upgraded to 1.1.1 version, I would like to upgrade my kafka-clients to 1.1.1 version to avoid down conversions. Is Spring Kafka 1.3.9 is compatible with kafka-clients to 1.1.1? Or Should I upgrade to 2.x versions of Spring Kafka, could someone help?

Comment: From the documentation , it is definitely compatible with kafka-client 1.0.x. Since the document says newer clients are usually able to communicate with older brokers, you should be good using 1.1.1 as well.  Link for the matrix  https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

Comment: Do you get errors when trying to use 2.x versions of Spring Kafka?

Comment: cricket_007: Yes, since Spring Kafka 2.x is based on Spring Framework 5.0, I am getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;). 

That's why I was checking whether kafka-clients to 1.1.1 is compatible with  Spring Kafka 1.3.9.

Comment: That error appears to be Spring related, not an error about a Kafka method missing. Specifically, your other Spring components would need upgraded as well

Comment: @cricket_007: Thank you for your response. Since I am not in a position to do the Spring upgrade now, I am checking for the kafka-clients to 1.1.1 to  Spring Kafka 1.3.9 compatibility. Do you see any issues here?

Comment: I don't see why not. Although, I don't regularly use Spring Kafka to give a definite answer

Comment: @Gary Russell : Could you please help here? Please excuse if this question is irrelevant.

I tested with Spring Kafka 1.3.9 and kafka client 1.1.1 and could see the everything fine, but the compatibility page says Spring Kafka 1.3.x  compatible with 0.11.0.x(**), 0.10.2.x, (PFB), hence raised this question.
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/wiki/Kafka-Client-Compatibility

Comment: @Nidhinjose We are planning to upgrade to kafka-clients to 2.3 while our spring-kafka is still 1.1. We can't do a major upgrade to spring-kafka (>1.3) upgrade as our spring version is 4.3.x. We can upgrade spring-kafka to 1.3.x
Can you please tell me if you faced any compatibility issues between spring-kafka 1.3.9 and kafka-clients 1.1.1 once you upgraded

Comment: @Vineel We haven't faced any issues with spring-kafka 1.3.9.RELEASE and kafka-clients 1.1.1 version. 

I read that though the 1.3.x supports using newer clients (e.g. 1.x, 2.x), automatic provisioning is not supported; the topic(s) must already exist, not tested this part myself

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nidhinjose we didn't find any issues in our upgrade